# How do I make Outlook show the weekday when receiving a meeting invitation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Whenever I receive a meeting invitation in MS Outlook 2013, it shows the date and time of the suggested appointment, but not which day it is on that date, such as Monday.

This has bothered me a lot, since November 11th doesn't mean as much to me as Tuesday does.

Answer (score 55):

Outlook uses the system-wide long date format setting, so by changing the long date format in the windows control panel to include 'dddd', outlook will also show the name of the day.

This setting can be found in the Region and Language section of the control panel. In English windows 7 you could search for "Change the date, time, or number format" to find it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It still works in Windows 10 (tested version 1903).  Go to Settings, choose "Time & Language" and then click "Date, time & regional formatting".  Then click "Change data formats" and pick the version of Long date you wish to use.

Comment: Funny: I configured the short date format to show week day, but not the long date format!

Comment: This works for Windows 11 too! Settings > Time & Language > Language & Region, then under Region see Regional Format and then you'll need to click on the button named "Change formats" to change the "Long date". No need to restart Outlook afterwards either, it works immediately.